# Accessing google drive with user name and password provided through code

Tags: android, google-drive-api, google-authentication, google-drive-android-api

I want to pass Gmail id and password and get the access to users drive. I don't want to use accounts that can be chosen using intent(account picker) instead i will provide edit-text to enter and user name and password, with which I should be able to access google drive for that user name and password.

Any suggestion how to do this?

Answer (score 0):

The only way to access google drive through an app is through the google drive API **OAUTH** system, it's well explained on their docs:

[About OAUTH](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/about-auth)

> > About authorization protocols
>
> Your application must use OAuth 2.0 to authorize requests. ***No other
>   authorization protocols are supported.*** If your application uses Google
>   Sign-In, some aspects of authorization are handled for you.